# PHP 2-d associative array: to add a key-value pair to the 2nd dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like these:

```
$a = ( 0 => ( 'name'=> 'Leonardo' ), 1 => ('name'=> 'Matthew' ), ... );
$b = ( 40, 50, ...);
```

And I want to produce a third array:

```
$c = ( 0 => ('name' => 'Leonardo', 'age' => 40), ('name' => 'Matthew', 'age' => 50), ...);
```

What's the array function to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map`. This works -

```
$res =  array_map(function($a,$b){$a['age'] = $b;return $a;}, $a,$b);
var_dump($res);
/** OUTPUT **/
array
  0 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Leonardo' (length=8)
      'age' => int 40
  1 => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Matthew' (length=7)
      'age' => int 50
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does this create a new instance of the array $a?

Comment: Nope. It just iterates through it. That's why I've used $res for it's return value. If you want to modify $a, replace $res with $a

Comment: Good answer. However, in my opinion, that is significantly harder to read than a simple for loop. I can imagine a lot of situations where it would be useful. I'll keep that approach in mind.

Comment: @DamienBlack I kinda think that too, but wherever I see array_map(), it just makes the intent clearer(you at-once know that the whole array is going to be iterated and will directly read the callback) :)

Comment: I guess it'll work with a sparse array or an associative array. My answer won't. So I think your answer is in fact superior. +1

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array `$a` and create `$c` as you go, no need for an array function:

```
$c = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    $c[$i] = $a[$i];
    $c[$i]['age'] = $b[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like that:

```
$c = array(0 =>
         array("name" => "Shuo", age => "29"),
           1 =>
         array("name" => "Superman", age => "350")
     );
```